# Unable to execute port when installing ImageMagick

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, macports, imagemagick

I'm trying to install ImageMagick by using MacPorts. I've successfully installed MacPorts by using their Mountain Lion .pkg file.

I open the terminal and run:

```
sudo port install ImageMagick
```

However what I get is:

> Error: Unable to execute port: Could not open file: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/graphics/ImageMagick/Portfile

Although the error message doesnt contain "permission denied", I tried setting `Portfile` and its first parent folder to `777`. And this obviously didn't solve my problem.

I have the latest Xcode installed.

Comment: Have you executed `sudo port selfupdate` before attempting to install ImageMagick?

Comment: Yes I did. But this operation didn't change the result because recently installed MacPorts tree is already up-to-date. What seems interesting is; the mentioned port file exists. It's not corrupted. It has the sufficient permissions (`-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel`) so why can't root install it?

Comment: I'm not on Lion, but `tarball` directory should be a sibling of `release`, not a child. Are you able to install other ports, like `libpng`?

Comment: This is a valid path: `/opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/graphics/libpng/Portfile`. The only directory in `rsync.macports.org/release/` is `tarballs/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the user macports read access to /opt

in Finder choose `"Go" -> "Go to Folder..."`
type `/opt` and `click "Go"`
in Finder choose `"File" -> "Get Info"`
click the little `padlock` icon in the lower right corner of the "opt Info" window
`enter your password` (or the username and password of an administrator) and `click "OK"`
click the little `plus` in the lower left of the "opt Info" window
choose `MacPorts` from the list and click "Select"

try again `sudo port install ImageMagick`

Comment: Command line approach: `port file foo` for the path to port `foo`'s Portfile, then `cd` there and `chmod +r Portfile`. Next `sudo port install foo` should work.