# Previous version of CGAL with Macports: "Error: Unable to execute port: Could not open file"

Tags: macos, macports, chmod, chown

I'm trying to install a previous port of cgal with macports. I'm following this How-to:
http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort

I already read this answer but it didn't solve for me. ([Unable to execute port when installing ImageMagick](https://superuser.com/questions/569386/unable-to-execute-port-when-installing-imagemagick)) -- Setting read permissions for *macports* user in /opt --

This is what i have done:

```
svn co -r 102134 http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/gis/cgal
sudo chown -R macports:macports cgal/
cd cgal
sudo chmod 777 Portfile
sudo port install
```

This is the error that i get

```
Error: Unable to execute port: Could not open file: /Users/#######/Downloads/cgal/Portfile
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried to set macports user in the /opt/local/etc/macports/macports.conf file to "root". Does the .conf file have to be reloaded in some ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok managed how to solve:

```
sudo mv cgal /private/tmp
cd /private/tmp
sudo port install
```

Answer (score -1):

I actually changed the permissions of `/tmp` as follows:

```
sudo chmod 755 /tmp
```

Comment: So this is not working for you?